# Update a value on specific column on specific time

Tags: php, mysql

Let's say I have a table like this

```
 ID |      DATETIME       | VALUE
 1  | 2011-12-10 01:22:46 |   NO
```

and for example real DATETIME now is 2011-12-10 00:22:46
I want the VALUE updated to YES when the DATETIME now is the same with the DATETIME on the table.

how to do this?

Comment: what do you mean by "matches" ? is equal ? the date part is equal ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use jquery ajax to make a heartbeating to the server each lets say half second in order to work with the delay if happens

1- download jquery or include it online

2- right this in a page that always opened I will give another solution if its not open

```
function updater()
{
    $.post('ajaxChecker.php');

}

setInterval( "updater()", 50 );
```

the above code send a request to page named ajaxChecker.php
then you need in that page to connect to the database 
I will assume you now that 
and in that 
make a query

```
$query = mysql_query("UPDATE tlbname SET `value` = 'YES' WHERE `datetime` = NOW()
```

");

Please check the reserved words for mysql and if you can't modify them make sure they are between ``

read about cronjobs to start it

Comment: Thanks for the answer. This is what I asked. Although is this efficient way? The table will have many rows. And about the open page. I'm not quite sure what you mean. That can't be guaranteed if I got it right. What is the other way?

Comment: cron job 
and if my answer is good for you please accept it 
and its a good way it will send requests to the server every 50

Comment: I've never setup a cron job any hint?

Comment: Yes sure no problem you setup it from your cpanel 
and determine the file and the time that called 
read the article here 
http://www.webmasters-central.com/article-blog/tutorials/cron-tutorial-managing-cron-tab-or-cron-job-is-easy/

Answer (score 0):

if you include time hh:mm:ss it's going to be quite dificult to match.. but otherwise it would be like:

```
update tlbname set value = 'YES' where datetime = @datetime
```

Comment: Yes I know the query. Maybe I wasn't clear. I'm asking how to update the value the moment that datetime is the same with datetime now(), in an efficient way.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps the best way to approach this is not to update a column at all:

```
ALTER TABLE tblname DROP COLUMN value;

ALTER TABLE tblname RENAME TO basetbl;

CREATE VIEW tblname AS
  SELECT id,
         `datetime`,
         IF(NOW() >= `datetime`, 'YES', 'NO') AS value
    FROM basetbl;
```

Now `` `value` `` will never be incorrect, and it will appear to have been updated the very instant the current time matches the yyyy-mm-dd_hh:mm:ss in `` `datetime` ``.

Alternatively, this dynamic computation could be pushed into your PHP code, with a query that looks for `` IF(NOW() >= `datetime`, ...) ``.

**The problem with the naive approach**, that of issuing an `UPDATE` every minute or more often, **is that you will miss an update**.  Any periodic `UPDATE` schedule — crond, an AJAX helper, MySQL's [EVENT](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/create-event.html) scheduler, whatever — will eventually miss a beat.  Perhaps the OS crashes, or MySQL is restarted, or, very plausibly, MySQL becomes so loaded with other queries that your `UPDATE` takes more than a minute to complete.

Even if the `UPDATE` is modified to retroactively correct missed updates, there will still be a window in which `` `value` `` is wrong.

Comment: thanks for the info. For now I used Create Event because I don't need so much accuracy. But I'll keep in my mind what you proposed.